# DVI-VGA adapter problem

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, display, resolution

Is it possible to add unsupported resolution when monitor is connected via DVI -> VGA (passive probably) adapter? The problem is that the monitor (Acer AL1916W) is reported as CRT monitor, mainly because it connected indirectly to the GPU (nVidia 9800GTX+ using driver v310.14 @ xubuntu 12.10). I've tried adding custom resolution with xrandr, but result was following:

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1680x1050_60.00
  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  31
Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

The persists on windows too, but it can be fixed by adding custom resolution from nVidia Control Panel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/q/377937/37165) May not be a duplicate; could be typo "DVI-I-0" instead of usual "DVI-0" in the linked post, or different hardware connection type requires different configuration? Any user with similar hardware setup should clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Please review my document how I fixed it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1owDutg6nqRXI-IwXMfPQ-m3UY_GIHOnT_YgZ7rJJIrs/edit?usp=sharing

I hope it would be helpful.

Thank you,
Alexander

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: To reviewers: This dated answer linked to a shared document that suggested to check monitor hardware information using Windows-only tool, then copied to X configuration in Ubuntu. If someone can figure out how to get similar information using Ubuntu/Linux only, this answer would have been useful. Decided not to quote the lengthy steps because of this reason.

Comment: Related: [Display monitor info via command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/371261/37165), may be useful to replace *the Windows-only step. This can only be clarified by users with similar hardware setup, however.