# Display monitor info via command line

Tags: monitor

Is there a way to query monitor information from command line? For example, get monitor model, similar to e.g. what `lspci` does for graphic card info, or whether it's currently on or off, things like that.

If possible, what kinds of basic information such as the above can be easily gathered? For example, is it possible to determine if monitor is in portrait or landscape position? Or if it has built-in speakers or not?

Command line is the preference, but if there's a GUI method, I'd like to hear about it, too.

Comment: What GPU do you have ?

Comment: 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6550M]

Comment: maybe you have more luck with: `sudo apt-get install xresprobe` and run `sudo ddcprobe`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67983/get-monitor-make-and-model-and-other-info-in-human-readable-form and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500521/linux-retrieve-monitor-names

Comment: See also [How to retrieve monitors configuration from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6118/310076) on Unix.SE

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$ grep "NVIDIA(GPU-0)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log |head -17| cut -d\: -f2
 Display (Samsung SA300/SA350 (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA
     3D Vision stereo.
 The EDID for Samsung SA300/SA350 (DFP-0) contradicts itself
     mode "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the
     EDID's valid VertRefresh range (56.000-75.000 Hz) would
     exclude this mode's VertRefresh (50.0 Hz); ignoring
     VertRefresh check for mode "1920x1080".
 The EDID for Samsung SA300/SA350 (DFP-0) contradicts itself
     mode "1280x720" is specified in the EDID; however, the
     EDID's valid VertRefresh range (56.000-75.000 Hz) would
     exclude this mode's VertRefresh (50.0 Hz); ignoring
     VertRefresh check for mode "1280x720".
 The EDID for Samsung SA300/SA350 (DFP-0) contradicts itself
     mode "720x576" is specified in the EDID; however, the
     EDID's valid VertRefresh range (56.000-75.000 Hz) would
     exclude this mode's VertRefresh (50.0 Hz); ignoring
     VertRefresh check for mode "720x576".
```

Comment: first line is the command. Note that this is not de official way to get vendor/model info from the monitor (but tragically it is often the only way), also it is GPU-vendor dependent.

Comment: Thanks - looking into `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` actually helps - it's a pity this is the only way.

Comment: I Found a howto: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Creating_and_using_edid.bin_via_xorg.conf

Comment: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy Refer to [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg#General) for more info. And of course this specific command requires an NVIDIA GPU.

Answer (score 61):

Yes there is, [read-edid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/get-edid.1.html) *hardware information-gathering tool for VESA PnP monitors*. This tool have two commands: `get-edid` and `parse-edid`:  *tools to retrieve and interpret monitor specifications using the VESA VBE DDC protocol*. [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) (*Extended Display Identification Data*) is a metadata format for display devices to describe their capabilities to a video source.

First:

```
sudo apt-get install read-edid
```

Then try:

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

Comment: Thanks thom - can you clarify how can I get monitor model using `get-edid` / `parse-edid`? When I ran the above, it did not print anything (not even in Section "Monitor") that would be similar to my monitor manufacturer / model. If that's OK with you, can you paste what you get on your machine and the monitor model you have, just for comparison?

Comment: Identifier "\QX:2d40"
 VendorName "\QX"
 ModelName "\QX:2d40"
I have to say that the EDID of my monitor is buggy as hell. So that is not really representative :-)

Comment: Thanks thom - looks similar on my end: `ModelName "LGD:8902"`, so looks like it is representative after all :) Also, it only displays my laptop monitor, but not the external one.

Comment: A lot of EDIDs are buggy. Manufacturers don't care and driverdevelopers are doing mostly workarounds. Best info is coming from closed source videodrivers. I extract it like this: `grep "Display" /var/log/Xorg.0.log |tail -1` for extensive info I use `grep "NVIDIA(GPU-0)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: This did not work for me.  I get open /dev/mem: Operation not permitted

Comment: @BrianMinton `get-edid` only works as root, and may also be further locked down depending on MAC policies (e.g. SELinux)

Answer (score 36):

### Case where `get-edid` does not show all monitors

Like mine, I have:

```
$ lshw -c display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

`get-edid` shows only the external monitor which is plugged to VGA port.

1. Install `read-edid`

   ```
    sudo apt-get install read-edid
   ```
2. Read EDID info directly from SYSFS tree, it should show all detected monitors

   ```
    ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c "echo {}; parse-edid < {}"
   ```

Comment: Method 2, reading the `edid` files from `sysfs` worked for me, thanks! It seems like `read-edid` probably needs to be updated.

Comment: mine showed this: This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Problem requesting slave address: Device or resource busy
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 5
1 potential busses found: 4
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 4
������ ����"x
$�YT�'PT�eP(00 DX���V�Q\0ddDX��
                               G�
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
<n

Comment: I used your method, and this helped me identify which edid I was reading from: `for edid in $(ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid); do echo $edid; edid-decode $edid | grep 'Display Product Name' ; done`

Answer (score 18):

Try

`xrandr`

(I used the program once when I was playing with dual monitor setup on Archlinux .)

You can find it in the `x11-server-utils` package. That package contains other stuff to play with like:

- iceauth, a tool for manipulating ICE protocol authorization records;
- rgb;
- sessreg, a simple program for managing utmp/wtmp entries;
- xcmsdb, a device color characteristic utility for the X Color Management
  System;
- xgamma, a tool for querying and setting a monitor's gamma correction;
- xhost, a very dangerous program that you should never use;
- xmodmap, a utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X;
- xrandr, a command-line interface to the RandR extension;
- xrdb, a tool to manage the X server resource database;
- xrefresh, a tool that forces a redraw of the X screen;
- xset, a tool for setting miscellaneous X server parameters;
- xsetmode and xsetpointer, tools for handling X Input devices;
- xsetroot, a tool for tailoring the appearance of the root window;
- xstdcmap, a utility to selectively define standard colormap properties;
- xvidtune, a tool for customizing X server modelines for your monitor.
  (information found in synaptic package manager)

Comment: Thanks Frank - can you clarify how do I get monitor model using `xrandr`?

Comment: ahah never use xhost? why

Answer (score 10):

`xrandr`, `xrandr --prop` and `xrandr --verbose` will give you some information with different level of detail.

Manufacturer-provided information can be found in the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) format.

To get and decode EDID, first check `xrandr` output to [find out](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/find-id-display-connected-linux-machine/) the used interface (e.g. `eDP-1`) and `apt install edid-decode`, then:

```
edid-decode </sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
```

Example output you can find [here](https://github.com/linuxhw/EDID/blob/master/Digital/Chimei%20Innolux/CMN1376/396347A5FC72). Replace `eDP-1` with your interface if needed.

Alternatively, `xrandr --prop` outputs EDID in hex format that you can feed to this online [EDID decoder](http://www.edidreader.com/).

I don't recommend using `read-edid` package because I had negative experiences with it (version `3.0.2`). In my case, `get-edid` outputs additional characters after the end that lead to a warning from `edid-decode` and `parse-edid` outputs random garbage in `ModelName` and `Identifier` fields.

Answer (score 9):

This gives you all the information you need:

`dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetCurrentState`

Comment: Maybe so, if you use Mutter window manager.

Comment: Excellent, a solution that doesn't need additional tools on a standard linux desktop

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. 
The monitor is connected using HDMI:

```
grep -i "monitor name" /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

Some window managers provide commands for listing output details. This one works if you are running `swaywm`:

`$ swaymsg -t get_outputs`

It generates the following output

```
Output eDP-1 'Unknown 0x408D 0x00000000'
  Current mode: 1920x1080 @ 60.049000 Hz
  Position: 0,0
  Scale factor: 1.000000
  Scale filter: nearest
  Subpixel hinting: unknown
  Transform: normal
  Workspace: 10
  Max render time: off
  Adaptive sync: disabled
  Available modes:
    640x480 @ 60.049000 Hz
    800x600 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1024x768 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1280x800 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1440x900 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1280x1024 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1680x1050 @ 60.049000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 60.049000 Hz

Output HDMI-A-1 'Samsung Electric Company C24F390 SRNABC123' (focused)
  Current mode: 1920x1080 @ 60.000000 Hz
  Position: 1920,0
  Scale factor: 1.000000
  Scale filter: nearest
  Subpixel hinting: unknown
  Transform: normal
  Workspace: 1
  Max render time: off
  Adaptive sync: disabled
  Available modes:
    720x400 @ 70.082001 Hz
    640x480 @ 59.939999 Hz
    640x480 @ 60.000000 Hz
    640x480 @ 66.667000 Hz
    640x480 @ 72.808998 Hz
    720x480 @ 59.939999 Hz
    720x480 @ 59.939999 Hz
    720x480 @ 60.000000 Hz
    720x480 @ 60.000000 Hz
    720x576 @ 50.000000 Hz
    720x576 @ 50.000000 Hz
    800x600 @ 56.250000 Hz
    800x600 @ 60.317001 Hz
    800x600 @ 72.188004 Hz
    1024x768 @ 60.004002 Hz
    1024x768 @ 70.069000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 50.000000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 50.000000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 59.939999 Hz
    1280x720 @ 60.000000 Hz
    1280x720 @ 60.000000 Hz
    1280x800 @ 59.910000 Hz
    1440x900 @ 59.901001 Hz
    1280x1024 @ 60.020000 Hz
    1600x900 @ 60.000000 Hz
    1680x1050 @ 59.882999 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 50.000000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 59.939999 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 60.000000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 60.000000 Hz
```