# can't get 5120x1440 resolution on samsung odyssey G9

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

I am running Ubuntu 21.04, trying to follow instructions at this link

[Single display unable to set 5120x1440 resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183735/single-display-unable-to-set-5120x1440-resolution/1325095#1325095)

I do the following:

```
cvt 5120 1440 -r

sudo xrandr --newmode "5120x1440R"  469.00  5120 5168 5200 5280  1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync

xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
```

the above returns

```
XWAYLAND0
XWAYLAND4
```

So I do

```
sudo xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND4 5120x1440R
```

Then try to select it

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND4 --mode 5120x1440R



X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x780
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

UPDATE - information requested:

```
Ubuntu 21.04
20U9001PUS
==
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:168 memory:e9000000-e9ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
==
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x23) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
    Identifier: 0x21
    Timestamp:  15755
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x23) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1440x1080 (0x24) 129.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1680 total 1920 skew    0 clock  67.19KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1087 total 1120           clock  59.99Hz
  1400x1050 (0x25) 121.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1632 total 1864 skew    0 clock  65.32KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1089           clock  59.98Hz
  1280x1024 (0x26) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x960 (0x27) 101.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  59.70KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total  996           clock  59.94Hz
  1152x864 (0x28) 81.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.78KHz
        v: height  864 start  867 end  871 total  897           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x768 (0x29) 63.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  47.82KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock  59.92Hz
  800x600 (0x2a) 38.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  912 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.35KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  624           clock  59.86Hz
  640x480 (0x2b) 23.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  29.69KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  500           clock  59.38Hz
  320x240 (0x2c)  6.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  15.00KHz
        v: height  240 start  243 end  247 total  252           clock  59.52Hz
  1680x1050 (0x2d) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1440x900 (0x2e) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x800 (0x2f) 83.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.85KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.99Hz
  720x480 (0x30) 26.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  29.85KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.71Hz
  640x400 (0x31) 20.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  25.00KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  409 total  417           clock  59.95Hz
  320x200 (0x32)  5.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  12.50KHz
        v: height  200 start  203 end  209 total  212           clock  58.96Hz
  1600x900 (0x33) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1368x768 (0x34) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x720 (0x35) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1024x576 (0x36) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  864x486 (0x37) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  720x400 (0x38) 22.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  24.83KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  413 total  417           clock  59.55Hz
  640x350 (0x39) 17.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  21.88KHz
        v: height  350 start  353 end  363 total  366           clock  59.77Hz
XWAYLAND8 connected 3840x1080+1920+0 (0x2b5) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
    Identifier: 0x2ca
    Timestamp:  15755
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  3840x1080 (0x2b5) 346.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  3840 start 4088 end 4496 total 5152 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1093 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1440x1080 (0x2b6) 128.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1680 total 1920 skew    0 clock  67.06KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1087 total 1120           clock  59.87Hz
  1400x1050 (0x2b7) 121.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1632 total 1864 skew    0 clock  65.18KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1089           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x1024 (0x26) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x960 (0x27) 101.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  59.70KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total  996           clock  59.94Hz
  1152x864 (0x2b8) 81.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.62KHz
        v: height  864 start  867 end  871 total  897           clock  59.78Hz
  1024x768 (0x2b9) 63.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  47.63KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock  59.68Hz
  800x600 (0x2a) 38.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  912 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.35KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  624           clock  59.86Hz
  640x480 (0x2b) 23.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  29.69KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  500           clock  59.38Hz
  320x240 (0x2c)  6.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  15.00KHz
        v: height  240 start  243 end  247 total  252           clock  59.52Hz
  1680x1050 (0x2d) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1440x900 (0x2e) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x800 (0x2ba) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  720x480 (0x30) 26.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  29.85KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.71Hz
  640x400 (0x2bb) 19.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  24.69KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  409 total  417           clock  59.20Hz
  320x200 (0x32)  5.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  12.50KHz
        v: height  200 start  203 end  209 total  212           clock  58.96Hz
  1920x1080 (0x23) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1600x900 (0x33) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1368x768 (0x34) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x720 (0x35) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1024x576 (0x36) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  864x486 (0x37) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  720x400 (0x38) 22.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  24.83KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  413 total  417           clock  59.55Hz
  640x350 (0x39) 17.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  21.88KHz
        v: height  350 start  353 end  363 total  366           clock  59.77Hz
  5120x1440R (0x2c2) 469.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  5120 start 5168 end 5200 total 5280 skew    0 clock  88.83KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1453 total 1481           clock  59.98Hz
==
```

Info from other post requested:

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
2 potential busses found: 3 7
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 3
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
You seem to have too many extension blocks. Will not continue to parse
Something strange happened. Please contact the author,
Matthew Kern at <(EMAIL REMOVED)>
```

Comment: Could you share output of: `sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; echo ==; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf"` in addition to output from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/371269/26246

Comment: will update question with output, assume you mean etc but there is no file, not surew here the xorg.conf file lives, i was wrong, i'm on ubuntu 21.04 sorry for bad info, will also update question with this

Comment: here you go https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nMdXS5JDMx/

Comment: You have integrated GPU, could you check you CPU model `sudo lshw -C cpu`  , also my previous command didn't bring info of monitor see with: `ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c "echo {}; parse-edid < {}"`

Comment: first request: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xN85bQRv8H/

Comment: 2nd command any success? for EDID data from monitor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132916/discussion-between-user-dz-and-user1130176).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the resolution is limited by GPU. CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] is an integrated GPU.

> ```
> Max Resolution (HDMI)‡ 4096 x 2304@24Hz
> Max Resolution (DP)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz
> Max Resolution (eDP - Integrated Flat Panel)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz
> ```

Source: [Intel i5-10210U](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/195436/intel-core-i510210u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz/specifications.html#specs-1-0-4)

You need a discrete Graphic adapter that support such resolution.