# How do I set a custom resolution?

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

I tried to use `xrandr` to set 1680x1050 as a new mode to VGA output, but it says:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  35
Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Answer (score 231):

First generate a "modeline" by using **cvt**
Syntax is: **cvt** *width height refreshrate*

```
cvt 1680 1050 60
```

this gives you:

```
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

Now tell this to **xrandr**:

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

Then you can now add it to the table of possible resolutions of an output of your choice:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00
```

The changes are lost after reboot, to set up the resolution persistently, create the file `~/.xprofile` with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00
```

You need to replace VGA-0 with your monitor connection. Use xrandr --listmonitors.

Comment: The connected device might not be `VGA-0`. If you get the message `xrandr: cannot find output "VGA-0"`, try running the following command: `xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"` (source: [xrandr on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr)). The output of that command should be the correct device identifier.

Comment: You do not need sudo with xrandr

Comment: I would like to add that I have the same error - and the above does not solve the problem at all

Comment: If you're on a VM, the display is usually `Virtual1` instead of VGA-0.

Comment: Ubuntu freezes when I try that solution. Using `Ctrl+Alt+F1` I can restart Unity, but then the custom resolution disappears

Comment: @thirdender after your command, with `xrandr --addmode "DVI-I-1" "1280x800_60.00"` gave me the same error "BadMatch", any idea?

Comment: @AquariusPower, try adding `--verbose` to your command and see if there is any useful output. Also see [Why do xrandr errors “BadMatch”, “BadName”, “Gamma Failed” happen?](http://askubuntu.com/a/727897/181902)

Comment: use `arandr` to find the VGA number instead of default VGA-0 as  in the answer

Comment: I get this error :
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38

Comment: After `xrandr --newmode` command - you can reconnect your display and it will automagically pick the newly added resolution ;)

Comment: You need to replace VGA-0 with your monitor connection. Use `xrandr --listmonitors`. See [How to fix error 'xrandr: cannot find output “VGA1”'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413304)

Comment: Also, for Ubuntu 17.10 I had to [Disable Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975094/how-to-disable-wayland-in-17-10-in-gdm3-login-screen) for this to work.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I have an MST dock, with a monitor that outputs 1080p over DVI. A DVI -> DisplayPort adapter. The monitor only reported 1024x768 to xrandr, but I knew it would support 1080p.

Comment: To only see active monitors, use `xrandr --listactivemonitors`

Comment: Thank you! Magic happens with this answer.

Comment: I get this error after newmode: "Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

Comment: It was not working in ubuntu 21.04, finally I have update the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf by uncommenting the line WaylandEnable=false to make it work. Thank you

Comment: This works, except that the login screen still runs at a low resolution. How do I make this resolution work at the login screen?

Comment: The modeline generated by cvt didn't work for me, maybe my monitor uses different standard. Using `grep -n Modeline /var/log/Xorg.0.log` I noticed that the newly added modeline was much different from the pre-existing ones. For example, my pre-existing modelines had `+hsync -vsync` whereas output of `cvt` had `-hsync +vsync`. So I had to change cvt output to match pre-existing modelines to make it work.

Comment: I had to use `cvt -r` to create a *reduced blanking* modeline for my 4K setup (3840x2160@60Hz). Without `-r` it didn't work.

Comment: @sebastian Thanks for sharing! This also works on my LG 2500x1080... Thanks for sharing! Works on Fedora 36 with XFCE Spin with xorg :)

Comment: if you get "Xrandr not recognizing '-HSync' as an option" - https://superuser.com/questions/1279750/xrandr-not-recognizing-hsync-as-an-option basically don't copy the "Modeline", just the part after that :-)

Answer (score 23):

How to set a custom resolution previously specified.  After executing the other steps defined to create the resolution, run:

```
xrandr -s 1680x1050
```

Comment: This yield an error: `Size [width]x[height] not found in available modes`

Comment: You have to do both "--newmode" to define a mode ("add mode to server") and "--addmode" to allow the newly added mode to be used for a given output ("add mode to output connetor"). Only then you can activate that mode for that output.

Answer (score 14):

How to set a custom resolution previously specified when **running multiple monitors**. After executing the other steps defined to create the resolution, run:

`xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1680x1050`

Replace `DVI-0` with your device-id, e.g. `VGA-0`

Comment: Great, how do I get my device-id?

Comment: @aggregate1166877 you can see it through "xrandr" without options. there is a list of devices and if they are connected. mines are DP-0 & DP-2

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to *thom* and *thirdender* this is basically a single command configuration based on the [most voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377944/163353).

```
RES="1920 1200 60" && \
DISP=$(xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/") && \
MODELINE=$(cvt $(echo $RES) | grep -e "Modeline [^(]" | sed -r 's/.*Modeline (.*)/\1/') && \
MODERES=$(echo $MODELINE | grep -o -P '(?<=").*(?=")') && \
cat > ~/.xprofile << _EOF
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode $MODELINE
xrandr --addmode $DISP $MODERES
_EOF
```

The above command will generate the desired `~/.xprofile` file. Just make sure you use the resolution (i.e. the `RES` variable) of your liking. [More info here](http://turlucode.com/xrandr-custom-resolution/).

You could replace

```
xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
```

with

```
xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | cut -d\  -f1
```

in `$DISP` variable if that does not work for you.

Comment: Thanx for this one.  It did the job for me. But to make it work, the user should run "cvt 1920 1200 60" command first. Because resolution isn't exist yet.

Comment: The script contains `MODELINE=$(cvt $(echo $RES) ...` which will run the required `cvt` command to generate the correct modeline.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely you have to take a look at autorandr, there seems to be no easier way.

This is the man page (from Ubuntu):
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/autorandr.1.html

And this is the source code:
https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr

Install it in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt install autorandr
```

Then just save your current config with:

```
autorandr -s myFaveConfig
```

and change config and save others with

```
autorandr -s myOtherConfig
```

Then just apply them whenever you want with:

```
autorandr [theConfigIwant]
```

for example:

```
autorandr myFaveConfig
```

will load the first config you saved in this example.

Nothing easier !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed the nvidia video driver?
I had problems with low resolution and discovered that my system was without nvidia driver. I don't have the exact command now, but is **something like** this, I suggest doing a resarch for it:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-[version]
```