# Connecting Ubuntu 13.10 box to a VIZIO E601i-A3 TV

Tags: 13.10, ati, multiple-monitors, hdmi

First, a briefe background on myself. I'm in IT. I've done both hardware and software tech support so I'm not an idiot when it comes to technology. However, I am totally new to linux boxes and hooking up to a TV... Figured it would not give me much difficulties... I was wrong... :(

I'm working on setting up my first media PC (it is a custom built box from my old company that they were going to throw away) running ubuntu 13.10 and I'm having issues connecting it to my VIZIO E601i-A3 TV.

Here is some hardware info on the media pc: 
Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU ES200 @ 2.50GHz x 2 
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR Sapphire Radeon HD 5450 1 GB DDR3 HDMI/DVI-I/VGA PCI-Express Graphics Card 100292DDR3L 
OS: Ubuntu 13.10 - 64-bit
Receiver: DENON AVR-931
Trying to connect to a VIZIO E601i-A3 TV.

My box runs with a regular monitor but when I plug it in via HDMI to my receiver to my TV, nothing shows up on the TV. I'm sure I have the correct settings selected for my receiver and TV. I have my TV plugged in from HDMI 1 to the receiver. My Xbox 360 runs fine plugged into the "game" hdmi port. I plugged in my media pc into the "DVD" hdmi port and selected that on the receiver and I get no signal. Since I know the "Game" port works, I tried there too, with no success.

In display settings it recognizes the TV as, "DENON, Ltd. 60"" So it knows it is there, and knows how big it is.

I'm thinking it is a driver issue?

I am able to change resolutions but still nothing pops up on the TV. I've tried the classic restart, of everything.

I have tried googling the issue but my googling skills are currently failing me.  I've also posted this to reddit with no help :(

Any help would be appreciated.

I'll also continue to update this with updates on things I've tried.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) You want to use a proprietary driver instead of the open-source gallium driver. [See here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

2) If your system is still unable to obtain and set a proper modeline via EDID, you can easily do so using the 3 terminal commands [shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) (cvt and xrandr) with the display connected DIRECTLY to the video card. Make sure you substitute VGA-0 with HDMI-0... Once your valid modeline has been set, you should be able to re-cable through your audio receiver.