# Display unknown after nvidia driver update, resolution stuck at 800x600

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I am currently running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04. I just installed the proprietary nvidia driver version 346 to resolve issues with another application and restarted my desktop to find that my main monitor is unrecognised and classed as an unknown display. The resolution is stuck at 800x600 in a 4:3 aspect ratio.

My graphics card is a Nvidia GTX 760. 
Drivers: Propietary version 345
Monitor: LG 24" 1920x1080 HDMI

Output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+800+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
HDMI-0 connected primary 800x600+0+212 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.3*+
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x2cc)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

Sorry for the formatting, It was fine outside of the preview.
The main emphasis there is the

```
HDMI-0 connected primary 800x600+0+212 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm 800x600
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a custom modeline for your display (Basically a custom "output"). Either that or your drivers aren't working properly... I had this issue with an old monitor and a custom modeline sorted it right away :P

You can add the native resolution modeline (1920x1080_60.00?) and then you should be able to switch to it, any other resolutions will probably need one too... EDID can be buggy with some monitors. :(

[How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

^Someone posted a guide here :D