# Ubuntu 14.04 resolution problem

Tags: 14.04, resolution

I have some problem with resolution. My monitor resolution is 1920x1080. 
At first when I installed ubuntu i had 800x600.. Now, after installing AMD driver, I only have 1600x1200 to choose like max resolution. 
Why is that? What should I do?

Any answer will be helpful :)

P.S. My graphic card is *Sapphire radeon HD 7850 (1Gb)*

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution/377944#377944

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

1. Use xrandr to make sure that the new mode can fit within the maximum framebuffer size

> ```
> xrandr | grep maximum
> ```
>
> 2. Use gtf to create a mode line
>
> ```
> gtf 1920 1080 60
> ```
>
> 3. Add new mode using xrandr
>
> ```
> xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60" 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
> ```
>
> 4. Add this newly added mode to the desired output (VGA/LVDS etc)
>
> ```
> xrandr --addmode VGA 1920x1080_60
> ```
>
> 5. Choose the new mode
>
> ```
> xrandr --output VGA --mode 1920x1080_60
> ```

Comment: Thanks man! :) 
 I do that, all. Now I have to choose for 1920x1080, but it looks like 4:3, not 16:9, how is that possible ? Do you have maybe some solution for that? 

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: please try again i edited some values in my answer.

Comment: xrandr --output CRT1 --mode 1920x1080_60
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

Nothing happend.. it same..