# 2nd monitor detected but no signal

Tags: monitor, amd-graphics

Beginner here,(Ubuntu 12.04.1LTS)

Currently this is my setup

1. Vga - vga (1st monitor).
2. Hdmi to Vga converter - vga (2nd monitor).
3. HD4870 with fglrx drivers.

After I connected my second monitor,Ubuntu detects it and shows it in my display settings and even my amd control center and i can even move my mouse over to the second monitor but everytime i turn on my second monitor,it shows no signal.

I have done:

1. Turned on second monitor from display settings.
2. Changed multi display properties to multi display with (1)/(2) in amd control center.
3. For Further Updates.

Seen many people post this so....(xrandr output)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 3520 x 1920
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP3 connected 1600x900+1920+89 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900       59.9*+
   1440x900       59.9 +
   1152x864       60.0 +   75.0  
   1920x1080      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1360x1024      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       60.0  
   1280x768       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   1152x648       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     70.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0  
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1360x1024      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0     60.0  
   1280x768       74.9     59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     70.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x480        60.0  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0
```

Comment: Is it actually a CRT monitor as it says? It's possible that you need to manually set your resolution in that case.

Comment: http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/40/919/L12678046.jpg , its an old monitor but I definitely don't thinks its crt. @MGodby

Comment: Check the specs for the monitor to find the max resolution and refresh rate supported by it. If it is lower than what xrandr says you are sending to it, use the most popular answer to this question to manually set your resolution and refresh rate to values known to work with your model monitor: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: @MGodby . The refresh rate is 60 and thats what i think xrandr says im sending.    Quick Update:Forgot to tell you guys this but sometimes my monitor works after full shutdown and restart but turns black after 5-10 seconds of working.Definitely not hardware problem because if i use the other monitor as main it works full-time.

Comment: Oh, this happens when some of the capacitors that drive the display die in the monitor. Does the monitor work with other devices?

Comment: If I use my vga - vga setup instead of my hdmi - vga to my second monitor (the blank one) it works so i dont think the capasitors are dead.Problem is I my gpu doesnt have 2 vga slots only 1 hdmi and 1 vga. @MGodby

Comment: I am having the same problem. Second monitor works in BIOS but not in Ubuntu 16.04.