# Creating custom screen resolution in Ubuntu

Tags: 15.04, screen, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 as native OS. My system's current resolution is `1366 * 768`.

I want to change my screen resolution to `1920 * 1024`.

I tried changing it from settings but that is not visible.

Below are the properties of my screen:

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm panning 1366x768+0+0
   1366x768       60.1*+   40.1  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 disconnected
VGA-1-1 disconnected
  1920x1080 (0xdc)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0xdd)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

Can I change my screen resolution to `1920 * 1024`?

Comment: It's not relevant whether it's a VM or not...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a custom resolution?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

The commands in order:

```
cvt 1920 1024
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

The latter line after `xrandr --newmode` is similar to the ouput you should get when using the `cvt` command, so copy the output from the "resolution_refreshRate" to the `+vsync` point and add it to `xrandr --newmode`.

Then:

```
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 resolution_refreshRate (don't use speechmarks)
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode resolution_refreshRate
```

If you want to make the changes permanent:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
  xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.