# Cannot change brightness in laptop

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, brightness, xrandr

I am trying to change the brightness of my laptop using `xrandr`, but I get this error.
Here's the segment:

```
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1368 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
DSI1 connected primary 1368x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1368x768      60.10*+
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
janreggie@janreggie-T100TA:~$ xrandr --output DSI1 --set backlight 10
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

My laptop is an ASUS Transformer T100TA, installed per Lubuntu 15.10 ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xrandr` has brightness parameter not backlight. You can set brightness level (eg. 0.9):

```
xrandr --output DSI1 --brightness 0.9
```

or use solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: okay, thanks. This works.

But is there a command that will increase my brightness (i.e. +0.1) or decrease it?

Comment: Your `FN` key is not working ? You can write a script and make a keyboard shortcut for it .

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, but can I create a script (which I may create a keyboard shortcut for) that, when run, it will inc/decrease the brightness by a certain amount?

Comment: system settings -> keyboard ->  shortcuts -> own shortcuts. You can assign button (combination) press to your script