# Screen size and shortcuts problems on Unity after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, shortcut-keys, 17.10

Two issues after the upgrade:

1. After login in Unity session, a dialog error appears, saying

**required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1,1), minum=(320,200), maximum=(8192,8192)**

I'd like to know what is asking the requested size (1,1) but don't know where to search... 
Anyway, I can work quite normally, but (don't know if it's related):

2. No global keyboard shortcuts work (such as volumeUp/Down, Super-L to block screen, etc.). Local shortcuts (such as Ctrl-Space to open my favourite launcher) work.

Before the upgrade none of the issues occurred.

```
# sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose
M14xR1
==
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:d2400000-d27fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:7000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
==
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
    Identifier: 0x41
    Timestamp:  38251
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030e4920200000000
        00150103901f11780a8e359358569029
        20505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101121b5668500012302020
        350035ae1000001a121b566850001230
        2020350035ae1000001a000000fe0039
        4d364452803134305748320a00000000
        00004131940100000001010a202000e1
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1366x768 (0x46) 69.300MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1398 end 1430 total 1470 skew    0 clock  47.14KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  776 total  786           clock  59.98Hz
  1360x768 (0x47) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0x48) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x768 (0x49) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x4a) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x4b) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x4c) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x4d) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  960x600 (0x4e) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x4f) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  800x600 (0x50) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x51) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x52) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x53) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x54) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  800x512 (0x55) 51.562MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  800 end  828 total  832 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  515           clock  60.17Hz
  700x525 (0x56) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  640x512 (0x57) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  720x450 (0x58) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
  640x480 (0x59) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x5a) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  680x384 (0x5b) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
  680x384 (0x5c) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
  576x432 (0x5d) 40.810MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  668 total  760 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  447           clock  60.06Hz
  512x384 (0x5e) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  400x300 (0x5f) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x60) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  320x240 (0x61) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  38251
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  38251
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  38251
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
```

Comment: Can you change the title of your post to be more descriptive?  Users who are browsing questions will most likely by-pass your post because the title doesn't provide any information.

Comment: Are you running in a virtual environment or on bare metal? If virtual and VMWare: are the guest additions and tools installed?

Comment: bare metal, no virtual

Comment: @jasmines, (1) add the output of `dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose` to the question. (2) Try changing screen resolution to a lower one then back to original, from system control - displays, then reboot to check.

Comment: Solved! If you wish to be awarded, you should convert your comment into answer in 3 hours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Try changing screen resolution to a lower one then back to original, from system control - displays, then reboot to check.

**Long answer**

> required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1,1), minum=(320,200), maximum=(8192,8192)

This error message looks like an `xrandr`one. So I asked for more graphics info to be added to the question.

```
dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose
```

Source: [Why do xrandr errors “BadMatch”, “BadName”, “Gamma Failed” happen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/710172/26246)

Possible issues:

1. Wrong or missing driver, but we found out it's ok from the output:

   ```
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   ```
2. Wrong virtual screen size stored in configuration, which could be reset by changing resolution. And this fixed it.

Comment: I didn't have the option to change the resolution from Displays settings as you suggested (apparently some other quirk causes "Could not get screen information" trouble). But then I tried changing screen size back and forth with `xrandr -s` command and it seems to have done the trick as well!