# AMD Ryzen Raven Ridge 2200G stuck at boot Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have the following specifications amd ryzen 2200G with motherboard msi b350 bazzoka, why is the kernel defaults to 4.15 (ubuntu 18.04) until the latest kernel 4.18.11 is always stuck on boot? I have to restart as many as I can, for log in.

Comment: Did you upgrade to the 4.18 kernel because you were having problems with the 4.15 kernel?  4.15.0-36 is the currently supported kernel for 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: yes, the default kernel of ubuntu 18.04 has a problem with my machine, I have to restart several times to log in due to stuck on boot.

Comment: I tried several versions of the kernel starting from 4.16, 4.17, 4.18, the result is stuck on boot.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1080460/edit) your question and possibly show us where it is stuck on boot?  The kernel may not be the issue.  It may be a driver or startup application.  Can you start to a LiveCD/DVD/USB without an issue?  Have you disabled Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: I have exactly this problem with an AMD Ryzen 5 2400G and Ubuntu 18.04.  If I boot normally it freezes with a blank screen.  However if I boot into recovery from the GRUB menu, and then choose "Resume boot" then it boots up properly and I have the expected high resolutions.  Does anyone know what is different between normal boot and recovery that could be making it work, and how I can change the normal boot configuration so that it works?

Comment: @richardneish, the difference is `nomodeset` in kernel boot option (grub boot settings) which is set in recovery mode. Many users having newest and oldest graphic adapters are using it as workaround till the new current driver gets fixed. You can also use this script in https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/26246 to compare both boots (without nomodset vs with nomodset), legacy driver may get loaded instead with nomodset.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to latest BIOS update of motherboard, install ukuu to install kernel, install latest kernel 4.19 rc5 and install mesa latest drivers. This will end boot issues and frequent crashes. Problems still persist, with upcoming kernel updates lets hope all issues will be resolved as AMD is contributing to Kernel is a big way.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the hang on boot by adding `nomodeset` to my boot options, following the suggestion by [user.dz](https://askubuntu.com/users/26246/user-dz)

As root, edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, find the line setting the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable and add `nomodeset`.  For me the result is

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`

Then run `sudo update-grub` to apply the change, and reboot normally.