# Ubuntu18.04 restarts with a black screen after installation

Tags: 18.04, graphics, gpu-driver

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS in an old desktop PC. Installation went good, but after a restart the screen stays black (thought that this could happen only in Windows!). It is my first attempt to see the "Linux" side of things and I am a little confused right now.

I searched here and found a temporary workaround by entering `nomodeset` in recovery mode and it worked. However, this is not a solution. In Additional Drivers I didn't find out anything that would let me install other graphics drivers. I don't have an NVIDIA or AMD card.

edit: graphic card = Intel® G41

Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00GHz × 2

Can someone give an idea what I should do?

```
   System:     Kernel: 5.0.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: Dell product: OptiPlex 380 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Dell model: 0HN7XN v: A01 serial: N/A BIOS: Dell v: A07 date: 06/13/2012
CPU:       Dual core Pentium E5700 (-MCP-) arch: Penryn rev.10 cache: 2048 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11969
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 1573 MHz 2: 1267 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) drivers: vesa (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev)
           Resolution: 1024x768@0.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 128 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-31-generic
Network:   Card: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
           driver: tg3 v: 3.137 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 440.1GB (2.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST3320418AS size: 320.1GB temp: 37C
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WDS120G2G0A size: 120.0GB temp: 39C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 293G used: 11G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 224 Uptime: 9 min Memory: 1920.5/4847.5MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: Welcome to AU, Would you please edit question and add more info about: Graphic card model/brand, Chipset if you know it. Also upload file generated by the debug command in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/26246

Comment: More information is needed and gets more chance for an answer, However Graphics is not my thing :), Good luck.