# Screen tearing on external monitor on 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, tearing

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Latitude E5570 and I have some screen tearing on an external monitor.

It is connected in HDMI but I also have the issue on another screen in VGA.

I don't have the problem on the laptop screen.

Here are some details for my graphic card:

```
Card: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: intel Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) version: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8
```

I tried to set the "TripleBuffer" and "TearFree" options in X11 (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`) but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this screen tearing problem?

Comment: try  extra `Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"` in your 20-intel.conf

Comment: skurty, Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you run the script at top of my answer here [display info script](https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/26246). Then add result link to the question. I don't have much experience with such issues but It may help, so our friends here my notice and find a solution for you. As much info you collect as quick you may get a answer.

Comment: Did you try to update the drivers? Also, did you try to boot from another Ubuntu version (live USB) and check if the screen tearing happens there as well? I'd suggest trying first Ubuntu 16 and then maybe Ubuntu 17/19.

Comment: With the "AccelMethod", I have more tearing.

Comment: For the display info script, I don't have the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

Comment: And for the drivers, here is my OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8 (which seems to be the latests)

Comment: check this question, it could help, i recently solved similar problem, in my case it was nvidia but your dell seems to have amd gpu alongside intel, regarrdsless maybe it could help.     https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368917/screen-tearing-on-intel-graphics-with-dual-monitor-setup-nvidia-and-intel/1370162#1370162