# How to set a custom resolution in 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, display, display-resolution, xrandr

This is basically the same question as [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) But that one is old and never got a solution it seems. And I'm now on Kubuntu 16.04.

So I have the same problem, I tried to add a new resolution using xrandr, this is what I did:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
Output:
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DP-4 "1920x1080_60.00"
Output:
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

And this is the output from "xrandr":

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm    3840x2160     60.00*+
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1920x1080_60.00 (0x260) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
    v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

I'm on a Lenovo p50 laptop, having disabled the intel VGA card and using only the Nvidia card, using Nvidia drivers.

Comment: have you tried the settings in kde-settings

Comment: The whole reason I'm attempting this, is that the display settings don't allow me to change resolution (only one available). Some bug I assume.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is (I think) is that you don't have sufficient permissions. If you are a `sudoer`, just run it again, except with `sudo`:

You need a "modeline", and then tell it to `xrandr` 
To set your modeline, use `cvt`:

```
$ sudo cvt width height refreshrate
```

Example:

```
$ sudo cvt 1680 1050 60
```

Note: It probably isn't necessary to run `sudo` on `cvt`.

This gives you:

```
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA)  hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25           1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059.    1089 -hsync +vsync
```

Provide this to `xrandr` (example):

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784  1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 - hsync +vsync
```

You will then add it to the possible resolutions:

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried before, and it doesn't seem like sudo makes a difference.

Comment: thankyou, this answer help me,,