# How to get a higher resolution with projector (unknown display)?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have connected a projector by VGA and I wonder why the maximum resolution available in Settings >> Devices >> Displays is just 1024x768 albeit it's a 1080p device. The label shows 'Unknown device' for the projector and just two additional 4:3 resolutions are available. Perhaps need for a driver? It's an Epson EH-TW3200, I'd like to know the general setting procedure when connecting to any device, though.

Graphics: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller, Ubuntu 18.04.

***Note/Edit:*** As stated, my question concerns the projector as a **second** device. I don't want to change the resolution of my main device. Under settings my main device is labeled as "Built-in display" and shows a bunch of possible resolutions to choose. The projector, however, seems to show up as "Unknown display" with only three resolutions which are too low. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823001) question doesn't provide sufficient information how to address the second display, since it's "unknown".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a custom resolution in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823001/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution-in-16-04)

Comment: @KristopherIves Thx, but I'm facing difficulties to follow the instructions of your link. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VGA problem miraculously solved itself after I plugged in a DisplayPort connector.