# Unable to access display settings GUI

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, system-settings

I recently plugged an old monitor to my laptop and it doesn't display red color. I want to configure it, but when i open Configuration > Settings > Displays (I hope my translation is accurate; in fact I work in Spanish) it doesn't allow me to change display settings. It says -I'm translating- "Unable to retrieve screen information". I attach a screenshot. I hope this isn't a duplicated issue; I've searched carefully and could not find anything similar.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old monitors (CRTs) used 3 guns (RGB) to create the images and didn't send configuration data back to the system like current screens do.

I've seen this particular problem before. It's quite likely that the Red gun in your CRT is shot and so no Red will be displayed. You can confirm this by trying to display orange which if I'm correct will display green.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It may be a hardware issue, but when i unplug it i cannot configure my laptop screen anyway. Any guess?

Comment: did you search for an answer to that question?

Comment: If your certain your screen supports other resolutions and you know what they are your answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: Yes, I did. In Spanish i googled the literal message and in English i tried to guess the translation. I found out that i can configure some options via 'xrandr', but I would want to do it through the grafic interface.

Comment: Once you add supported resolutions via `cvt` and `xrandr` I think you'll find that you can.

Comment: Hello. I did it and it is still not working.