# xrandr - fail to set custom screen resolution (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have followed the steps [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) to add a new custom resolution to my Ubuntu (16.04) machine. I got the same error that the person who asked the question got, however the answer did not solve my problem. Here's what I did:

```
cvt 1600 900 60
```

that gave me:

```
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

I then added the output using xrandr:

> ```
> sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
> ```

But then, when I tried to add the new mode with:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode eDP1 1600x900_60.00
```

I got the following error message:

> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)   Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)   Serial number of failed request:  37 
>   Current serial number in output stream:  38

I input the following command to obtain my screen name:

> xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/([A-Z0-9]+) connected.*/\1/"

and obtained

> eDP1

Does anyone know a workaround or what is wrong with my commands? I have no xorg.conf file. Do I need it or it should be possible only using `xrandr`?

Comment: What machine are you using?  What is the native resolution of the display?  what version of the nvidia drivers are you using?

Comment: I am using an Acer Aspire E15 i5.  Don't really know the native configuration