# How to set appropriate screen resolution for 19" monitor using xrandr?

Tags: 22.04, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to set custom 1920x1080 resolution for 19" Dell monitor.
It's not listed in available resolutions but I know it's the appropriate resolution
for this monitor.

I've followed [xrandr - fail to set custom screen resolution (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871558/xrandr-fail-to-set-custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-16-04) as well as https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/

my `/etc/profile.d/external_monitor_resol.sh` contains:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 1920x1080
```

then I ran:  `xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1920x1080` and output I got:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: xrandr works with X11Server not with wayland. Switch over to the XSession (Login Screen) and try again

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLVHz7rrP8U guide
which led me to solution. Main step was to edit the grub file.