# Nvidia drivers left me stuck at the wrong screen resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 635, and I installed the drivers for it with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but now my screen resolution is off and can't be changed in the display subsection of the system settings. Specifically, my screen resolution is stuck at 1024x768 (with no other options presented) while my native resolution is 1920x1080.

Relevant `lspci` lines:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 635] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 635]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

How can I change my display back to its native resolution?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: I've added those lines.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6: Could you give me an idea of why that's causing my system to have the problems its having?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: @Pilot6: Secure boot was already disabled.

Comment: @ElderGeek: `xrandr -s 1920x1080` gives the error `Size 1920x1080 not found in available modes`.

Comment: Did you create one with cvt first?

Comment: @Elder Geek: When I add the mode from `cvt` with `xrandr --newmode ...`, I get `xrandr: failed to get size of gamma for output default`.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your post (but include the full command) as [comments  can be deleted for a number of reasons.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) Thank you for helping us help you!