# Desktop zoomed in after fresh install

Tags: zooming

Before anyone marks this as already answered then I'll stop you there as all their fixes doesn't work for me.

Long story short (not really) this is my 5th install of Ubuntu (all previous installs not working so not a good first impression) and after fresh install on a separate hard drive I bought after partitioning not working I log in my desktop and it is zoomed in (possibly bottom right?) and everything I try leads to another problem. First I tried to install nvidia drivers and I get unable to fetch errors, I do it through the menus but I cannot even access anything so it has to be in the terminal, I try zoom in and out zoom works fine but no taskbars on the left or top instead it makes my window the same size as the screen. As you can see one problem leads to another. All I can do is right click, I've managed to get to all settings through 'change desktop background' but not all settings actually show due to the window size.

Every fix I find doesn't seem to help me as this is my first time logging on so I have no additional software doing it and all other fix tells me to go into a program or a menu which I cannot.

I am very stuck with only being able to right click so any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Bit of info:
The resolution is set to `640x480` and I cannot change it through the menu or terminal, then I go to install drivers and then another issue and so on...

What I did to try to get the drivers was

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

I'm sure 375 is the latest for me but 367 was the only one that did anything but it comes up with 'failed to fetch' along with 'temporary failures'.

Comment: You have to show us how you tried to get the nvidia drivers and the exact error message you got.  We don't know what you have actually done that doesn't work.  Without providing details, the only thing we can do is giving you the steps you're saying you have already read.  Again, we don't  know which ones you've read.  Please make a reference to some of the steps from the questions you've read that doesn't work for you.  If we can see how you are applying the steps, we can see why they are not working.

Comment: @L.D.James the fixes other people have is to go into settings but all I can do is right click and go off of that. I've tried changing the resolution in terminal 'xrandr -s 600x480' (no other sizes work) and it comes up with 'size 'the size I enter' not found in available modes'. I do run ubuntu in nomodeset as if I don't, it would just black screen, that may be linked to 'not found in available modes'?

Comment: I'll give you the exact steps in a second based on your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run these steps to install the nvidia Drivers.**

```
$ sudp apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53943/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-desktop-zoomed-in-after-fresh-install).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your best resolution using `xrandr` command mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried and it says 'not found in available modes'