# Problem with custom resolution ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, display-resolution, xrandr, gamma

I installed Ubuntu 17.04. I have a problem with the screen resolution, I want to set a resolution of 1366x768 but the max resolution that Ubuntu allows me is 1024x768.

I tried to increase the max resolution to 1366x768 using the `xrandr` command, but this command does not work properly.

If I run the command I get the following error:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default)
```

Comment: Could you add  output of `xrandr`and `sudo lshw -C video`commands?

Comment: See the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377944/723193) in [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)