# (Ubuntu 17.10) Add/change screen resolution

Tags: xorg, 17.10, screen, display-resolution

I upgraded from ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 (32 bit) and I wanted to set resolution to 1600x900.

after lot of researching I did this (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374840) 
[Ubuntu login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ieR3.jpg)

( It's saying ----In Ubuntu 17.10, restart your system. At the login screen, under the password field, you’ll see a gear icon. Just click on it and you’ll see two options here.

The default Ubuntu means it will be using Wayland while Ubuntu on Xorg obviously means it will use Xorg. You can select Ubuntu on Xorg to use Xorg here.----)

And after that  I did this [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

I rebooted pc and on login screen I clicked on gear and chose ubuntu on xorg
and I am having blank screen now.

I rebooted and selected option Ubuntu, then it starts fine. but ubuntu on xorg is not opening nor the resolution is fixed.

Thanks For Help.

Answer (score 2):

**I found a solution.**

Here's what I did.

1. Reinstalled Ubuntu 17.10
2. Went to Terminal and executed:

   ```
   xrandr
   ```

   You will get your monitor name. It was `VGA-1` in my case.
3. Then run `cvt <width> <height> <refreshrate>`, in my case is:

   ```
   cvt 1600 900 60
   ```

   This gives you:

   ```
   # 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
   Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
   ```
4. Now copy the part after `Modeline` to `xrandr`:

   ```
   sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
   ```
5. Then you can now add it to the table of possible resolutions of an output of your choice:

   ```
   sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00
   ```
6. The changes are lost after reboot, to set up the resolution persistently, create the file `~/.xprofile` with the content:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
   xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00
   ```