# xrandr outputs errors when I try to add a new resolution

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to add my own resolution, 1280x720 75Hz on my Nvidia card.

I've only come across this one method using `xrandr`, where you use `cvt` to get the parameters for your resolution and refresh rate, input it with `xrandr --newmode`, and then use `xrandr --addmode` to your display output. However, I get this error at the `--newmode` step:

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x720_75.00"   95.75  1280 1360 1488 1696  720 723 728 755 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
Serial number of failed request:  53
Current serial number in output stream:  53
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it possible that you are creating a resolution that your monitor will not work in? It would be good if you could get all of the resolutions possible for your particular monitor at 75HZ.

Comment: No, it's a possible resolution in my Windows 10 install (running dualboot), and my monitor's native resolution is 1920x1080. It should 100% work.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what driver ? xrandr does not work with wayland (17.10) or the nvidia driver. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution and post the output of cvt with the resolution you want