# xrandr cannot find mode, but shows up in list

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

[How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution/1046946#1046946)
I followed the instructions here, but xrandr cannot find the mode when I try to add it (I am using 1440x709 to test)

(for reference i am on a GTX 1050 Ti with NVIDIA driver 390.67)

Updated screenshot from terminal:

[image: Image]]

Comment: From what I see the resolution you are trying to setup is on a disconnected DVI-D-1 interface. DVI-D-0, which has connected Screen 0, does not support that resolution. Therefore, it cannot find it. Then you try to setup a resolution on a disconnected port. I am not sure that works. Also read the answers in the link you provided carefully. First make a new mode and then add it. Only adding inexisting mode will not work, and in the end monitor will probably not support it.

Comment: i tried that AFTER trying it on the working DVI-D-0, and i am trying to add it to the output, i already made the mode with newmode, and i have tried with other resolutions (ones that have worked in other OSes)

Comment: Have you tried `cvt 1440 709` and then copied mode line?

Comment: thats exactly what i did, i followed the exact steps

Comment: I have tried and it worked. can you go through this, may it helps `pratap@i7-6550U:~$ cvt 1440 709
# 1440x709 59.80 Hz (CVT) hsync: 44.07 kHz; pclk: 82.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x709_60.00"   82.50  1440 1512 1656 1872  709 712 722 737 -hsync +vsync
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xrandr --newmode "1440x709_60.00"   82.50  1440 1512 1656 1872  709 712 722 737 -hsync +vsync
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1440x709_60.00
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1440x709_60.00
pratap@i7-6550U:~$`

Comment: @PRATAP that did not work for me. my displya is DVI-D-0, and i recieved errors when doing the addmode : X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38

Comment: @ALPHA_exe i have gone through the screenshot you attached. i did not find about "newmode" in the screenshot. if you have already tried adding newmode of 1440x709 can you try adding any newmode which is not displayed when you enter `xrandr` and try?

Comment: @PRATAP i have tried adding several other newmodes with the exact method, and they gave that same error i mentioned before

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Only lower resolutions are allowed.
2. I needed `sudo` for `newmode` and `addmode`.
3. I edit the mode line, e. g. `1400x700_60.00` to `1400x700`.
4. I wrote a sh script to set Resolution on each reboot.

Check with `xrandr` without Extension if `addmode` was successful.