# Display not detected after reboot - AMD

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have performed an update via `apt-get` and, after the reboot, one of the displays is not detected anymore. Both the displays I have work, but they simply mirror each other.

I have tried via Displays settings but only a ''built-in display'' is detected.

[image]

**My system's specifics are**:

Distributor ID: 
Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS 
Release:    16.04 
Codename:   xenial

Graphic card:
 
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] [1002:6985]

Dirvers:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] [1002:6985]
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0b0c]
65:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:aae0]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How many displays do you have? Are they connected through HDMI or VGA?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xrandr` to manage your displays:

- to automatically detect displays:

  ```
  xrandr --auto
  ```
- to set the displays to extend each other you can do something like:

  ```
  xrandr --output YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME --left-of VGA_NAME/HDMI_NAME
  ```

you can find more at the [docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Toggle_external_monitor)

Comment: When I type `xrandr --auto`,   I get this message:   `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`.   What can it be ?

Comment: @DavideChiarugi perhaps you have to add a new mode in xrandr to allow it to detect your other display. What do you see when you type `xrandr --output ` and hit tab to see the available displays?

Comment: The only possible available display that I obtain is "default"

Comment: @DavideChiarugi Have a look at this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)