# HDMI (DP-3) no output 2560x1600 59-60Hz in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, xrandr

There's no HDMI (which is DP-3 in xrandr) output on 2560x1600 59Hz or 60Hz in Ubuntu 19.04.
Whether I try it with intel or the nvidia chip, the output is limited to 30Hz. Please note that 2560x1600 with 60Hz is working fine in Windows 10 with the same cable and monitor.

Adding custom modes with xrandr on 60Hz won't work. Changing configuration won't work. However *things will work as long as I keep the 30Hz setting with the custom xrandr setting*.

Notebook: Dell Precision 5530

lspci -kvnn:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:3ec4] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: ec000000-ed0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [1028:087d]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3e9b] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 158
    Memory at eb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [1028:087d]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ed510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [1028:087d]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at ed528000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller [8086:a379] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller [1028:087d]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ed527000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a36d] (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at ed500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:a36f] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM [1028:087d]
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at ed51e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at ed526000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a368] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 7f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a369] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 7f801000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller [8086:a360] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 143
    Memory at ed523000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a353] (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at ed51c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at ed522000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at ed521000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [8086:a340] (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00007fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-ea0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000b1ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [1028:087d]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [8086:a338] (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3b, subordinate=3b, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ed400000-ed4fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [1028:087d]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [8086:a33c] (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3c, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ed300000-ed3fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [1028:087d]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 [8086:a330] (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3d, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ed200000-ed2fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [1028:087d]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a30e] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 159
    Memory at ed518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ed100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [1028:087d]
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ed520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:a324] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [1028:087d]
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P1000 Mobile] [10de:1cbb] (rev a1)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [disabled] [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at ed000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:4010]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at ed400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:087d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at ed300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 [144d:a808] (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 [144d:a801]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at ed200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=33 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [168] #19
    Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1600, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 2560x1600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
   2560x1600     59.97*+
   2048x1280     60.20  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   2048x1080     24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Please help with this issue, or please help me file a bug with this. This should work out of the box.

Comment: the output said you're `4480 x 1600` resolution selected. did you try `xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 2560x1600`

Comment: no, that's not the issue. not even close. that's the resolution of both displays added up.

Comment: Have You run `xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 2560x1600 --rate 59.97` or any other mode that is listed by xrandr for this monitor ?

Comment: Do You have `nvidia` drivers installed? Then You can use `nvidia-settings` program and there `X Server Display Information` to try to change resolution and refresh rate.

Answer (score 0):

My 4K monitor and adapter rated at 60 Hz wouldn't work at 60 Hz either. Like yourself though it worked at 30 Hz. Then I tried 45 Hz and it worked too. I kept increasing it until 54 Hz which also worked. So I created a configuration at 54 Hz and placed it in `xorg` configuration. For me the jump from 30 Hz to 54 Hz relieves a lot of stress on the eyes. I don't think I loose that much dropping down from 60 Hz to 54 Hz.

Here is my `xorg` configuration snippet:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-1-1"
    Modeline "3840x2160_54.00"  637.50  3840 4152 4568 5296  2160 2163 2168 2230 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "3840x2160_54.00"
EndSection
```

You need to use `cvt` to create your `Modeline` above:

- [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a solution to my problem, and won't help fixing the bug