# External monitor doesn't work at full resolution on Thinkpad T480s

Tags: display, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I have an external monitor capable of 3440 x 1440 resolution. Up until about a week ago, I was using it just fine at that resolution on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Now it won't let me go above 2560 x 1080 (anything lower than this works just fine too). When I try 3440 x 1440, the screen goes black and I have to revert to a lower resolution. I assume it was a recent software update that caused this, although I am not sure what. Any ideas what I should try?

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for mwhite: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:157 memory:e7000000-e7ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Try adding 30hz mode manually. It's working for me at 60hz in windows, but not under ubuntu. My question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164615/hdmi-dp-3-no-output-2560x1600-59-60hz-in-ubuntu-19-04