# How do I increase resolution on ZOTAC ZBOX-CI549 NANO?

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I need to set higher resolution on my Zotac XBOX. This is list of resolutions which I see in the dropdown box:

[image]

I need to select this 1680x1080 resolution. Currently if I select it, it doesn't work and goes back to currently selected 1280x800. This resolution is supported by Windows on same PC and also I've clearly seen it working during first logins to Ubuntu after installation. But somehow later it has downgraded to 1280x800. This is output of my xrandr:

[image]

I've added this last line from cvt, but as I said earlier, it doesn't work:

[image]

It seems that I need to change something in video driver, but there is no Linux drivers on ZOTAC website. Also there is no driver here:

[image]

What else can I try to do? I clearly remember that this resolution worked successfully on this Ubuntu 18 with this hardware.

**UPDATE**: setting different crtc also fails:

[image]

May be problem is video card driver, this is how windows uses this device according to GPUZ:

[image]

**UPDATE2**: interesting observation: initial system login dialog somtimes has good resolution. And also if I install xorg intel driver, then I get good resolution, but mouse and keyboard are dead.

**UPDATE3**: I've found out that if I disconnect PC from 220V, turn off monitor, then start everything again, then resolution is good. If during my work screensaver starts or cable gets reconnected, then it goes to this 1280x800 mode and there is no way back except this hard restart. (This device has alike problems on Windows, but it is not about limited set of modes there, but monitor sometimes can't resurrect at all after cable reconnect). Also as requested, here is output of **dpkg -l bolt**:

[image]

**UPDATE4** As I have noticed, screen saver can cause resolution degradation, so I had to turn it off in this fancy way:

[image]

Comment: Did you by any chance set a modeline with cvt?

Comment: yes, it was set using cvt

Comment: Did you nby any chance follow every step here? https://askubuntu.com/a/377944/225694

Comment: this is exactly what I did, I created this extra mode, but it doesn't work

Comment: have you tried manually setting the crtc option with xrandr. The default --crtc value is automatically chosen by xrandr, and in most cases works fine, but in your case it may actually need to be set on its own. You can run `xrandr --verbose | awk '/ conn/{flag=1;}/discon/{flag=0}flag'  | grep -i crtc` and it will give you the current crtc setting for the output as well as the other possible values.

Comment: your cmd gives this output in two lines:  CRTC:       0 CRTCs:      0 1 2, I've updated the question showing this unfortunately doesn't help also.

Comment: What is the make and model of the screen you have attached to DP-1? Also the output of `sudo lshw -C display` Please [edit] thid information into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: The output of `dpkg -l bolt` might also be useful to [edit] into your question as according to [your specs](https://www.zotac.com/us/product/mini_pcs/ci549-nano) your system supports display port via a Thunderbolt 3 to Display port adapter.

Comment: Please [edit] the requested information into your question. I'd like to help you, but it will require some small effort on your part.

Comment: @ElderGeek, I've added some more information including what you have asked.

Comment: Dear @ElderGeek , your bolt solution worked properly! Please post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @stiv according to the information you added to your question, bolt was already installed and was already the newest version. I don't see what solution you are talking about. If you came up with one, feel free to self answer for the benefit of those who are having the same problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @ElderGeek, I've found a workaround, I've bought cable like this to connect monitor via thunderbold:

[image]

it works perfectly without any extra setup.