# Set external monitor's resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, intel, toshiba

I know theres already a question talking about it, I know. Here's the answer that "solved" my issue:

https://askubuntu.com/a/377944

It gave me the following result (notice how 1600x900 is now listed!!)

[image: cool ass screenshot]

Sadly, when I switch to the said resolution, my monitor (Toshiba) outputs a "No signal" message. I then have to wait 20 seconds for Ubuntu to switch back to 1360x1024, which is too small for me. (I dont know if that helps, but 1366x768 doesnt works either!)

Any tips?