# Added a new resolution with xrandr and my monitor now is a black screen that says out of scale

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

I was trying to add new resolutions since I only had 1024x768 and 800x600 in **Displays**. I didn't manage to make anything new show up in the resolution box in **Displays**. I used commands from [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)
and I got a long line at the bottom with the new resolution and all those numbers when I used xrandr.

I don't remember what it said and my .bash_history didn't save the commands I used because I got a power failure with the terminal open. Now during boot everything becomes tiny midways and when I get to the logon screen, I get a black screen saying "out of scale"; that is from my monitor when the resolution doesn't fit. I already tried

```
xrandr --size 1024x768
xrandr -s 0
xrandr -s 1024x768_60.00
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Nothing seems to work, but I know I opened the terminal with ctrl + alt + T because I pressed backspace and it did the sound that it does when there is nothing written there. I also tried recovery mode and it works fine but changing my resolution doesn't fix it for when I do a normal boot.

Is there a way to reset this back to default?

Comment: Did you use the resolution numbers for your monitor?  Can you unplug display and plug back in or use a different cable type(that's handy)?

Comment: i used the numbers i got after Modeline when i used the cvt command,i can unplug and plug back but i dont have another cable,my monitor is old and is 4:3 so i looked up higher resolutions for 4:3 since i could use those in windows 7,i belive i tried 2048×1536 if i renember correctly

Comment: Have you rebooted yet? Sometimes xrandr won't save custom settings.  You can only go up to max resolution of your monitor, not what your OS can output, sounds like you went pass max

Comment: yes i rebooted,had to get to recovery mode to try to fix

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem changing from xorg drivers to nvidia drivers and everything is working perfectly,followed this guide:https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem