# Radeon Vega does not support 1368x768 resolution

Tags: graphics, display-resolution, radeon, amd-graphics

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad C340 laptop (14 inches) recently and have been having problems with the screen resolution.  This laptop has an AMD Ryzen CPU and a Radeon Vega 10 APU.  I tried Ubuntu 20.04 beta, Ubuntu Mate 20.04 beta and Ubuntu 18.04.04.  All are running Linux 5.+ kernels that support the `amdgpu` driver.  The behaviour was more or less the same.

The core of the matter is that the graphics card supports only a handful of screen resolutions, and not 1378x768, which is the most user-friendly resolution at this screen size.  Here is what is supported according to `xrandr` (Windows also sees the same ones)

```
~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3072 x 1728, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 3072x1728+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+
   1680x1050     60.01  
   1280x1024     60.01  
   1440x900      60.01  
   1280x800      60.01  
   1280x720      60.01  
   1024x768      60.01  
   800x600       60.01  
   640x480       60.01
```

I've read online that fractional scaling at a higher resolution might also work (or scaling fonts by changing dpi), but lets face it, this feature is at its current state quite horrible and does not work well. (font scaling is particularly bad, fractional scaling on Ubuntu 20.04 was bearable, but was still a major downgrade from my 6-year old laptop running Ubuntu 16 at 1368x768)

I tried adding a custom resolution to `xrandr` using this guide ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)), but that only resulted in a black screen.

Any suggestions to what can be done? Is it hopeless with the graphics card and should I just stay away fro AMD/Radeon in the future?