# External monitor works on all resolutions except highest

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have Kubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Latitude 5501 laptop. I connect an external monitor (IIYAMA XUB2792QSU-B1) to HDMI port. The monitor's resolution is 2560x1440.

KDE's System Settings lists all the resolutions up to 2560x1440, but if I choose that highest resolution, the monitor displays a No signal message. Other resolutions (2048x1280 etc.) work normally.

How can I fix this, or how can I diagnose it further?

I have another laptop (HP Probook 440 G6), also with Kubuntu 18.04, that works properly with the same monitor and same cable.

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 0d)                                                                                                                                                                                                
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (rev 02)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0d)                                                                                                                                                             
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model                                                                                                                                                             
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)                                                                                                                                                                                              
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake LPC Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
39:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3a:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5410 (rev 01)
```

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2048 x 1280, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32                                                                                                                                 
   512x384       60.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   512x288       60.00    59.92                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   480x270       59.63    59.82                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   400x300       60.32    56.34                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   432x243       59.92    59.57                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   320x240       60.05                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   360x202       59.51    59.13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   320x180       59.84    59.32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DP-3 connected primary 2048x1280+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm                                                                                                                                                                                  
   2560x1440     59.95 +                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   2048x1280     59.99*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1920x1200     59.95                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1600x1200     60.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   1680x1050     59.88                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   1600x900      60.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   1280x1024     75.02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   1440x900      59.90                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1024x768      75.03    60.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   800x600       75.00    60.32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   720x576       50.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   720x480       60.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
```

Comment: It could be a limitation in one or more of: motherboard or GPU or HDMI port or HDMI cable. Have you checked the specs of the GPU and the exact laptop model you have to ensure everything should support that resolution? Specifically the HDMI port on the laptop and the cable? What HDMI versions are they? See the HDMI version/data rate table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions

Comment: @codlord, GPU apparently is Intel integrated graphics, in i7-9850H; Intel site says it supports up to 4096x2304@30Hz (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/191047/intel-core-i7-9850h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html). Laptop specifications says that HDMI port is HDMI 2.0 (https://www.dell.com/ru/business/p/latitude-15-5501-laptop/pd), which, IIUC, supports 4K. The cable marking reads "High speed HDMI cable ^ AWM style 20276 80°C 30V VW-1 Hotron" (^ stands for some symbol like UR mirrored), I don't know what to make of it. But a different laptop works with this cable well.

Comment: o.k. so it would appear that as you say everything *should* support that resolution. Only thing I can think of is try a lower refresh rate, I have seen issues like this in the past where people have "fixed" it by adding/setting a 50hz refresh rate (even though the monitor says it should support 59.95). First thing I would do is get it running on your working laptop and check the monitor on-screen-display to see what refresh rate it's reporting, is it actually working at 59.95 or less? See here for adding custom res: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution#377944

Comment: @codlord, another laptop also uses 59.95 (monitor itself reports it as 60, KDE System Settings reports 59.95). I've tried manually adding 50hz or even 30hz, none worked, 30hz displayed "Out of range" message on monitor, instead of "No signal".

Comment: Only last suggestion I have is generate a modeline with reduced blanking clock timing in `cvt` like `cvt -r 2560 1440 60` and try adding the resulting modeline as a custom resolution. Other than that I would try raising a helpdesk issue with Dell support.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but I found that I can connect the same monitor to the same laptop using the same hdmi cable, but not directly to hdmi port, but to a usb-c port using a usb-c—hdmi adapter, and in this configuration it works properly on all resolutions.