# Help needed with monitor resolution issue since new kernel, related to EDID

Tags: kernel, xorg, display, display-resolution

since upgrading to 20.04 my system boots into 640x480 and I am unable to change the resolution, I tried following the instructions here: [How do I set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution#377944) to force a custom resolution, but this has not worked.

If I boot into Kernel 4.15 instead of 5.4 at grub, everything is fine.

By examining syslog and xorg logs it looks like my system can't read the EDID of my monitor when using the new kernel, in case you want to look for yourself:

xorg log booting into kernel 4.15: https://pastebin.com/mDD8Wsev
syslog booting into kernel 4.15: https://pastebin.com/dquKP93n

syslog booting into kernel 5.4: https://pastebin.com/WdPn1WHD
xorg log booting into kernel 5.4: https://pastebin.com/KKY60rQR

I have looked into ways to force an EDID, and they talk about doing so in the xorg.conf - A problem I have is I seem to have no xorg.conf - that is /etc/X11/ there is simply no xorg.conf file
in X11/xorg.conf.d/ - there are .conf files such as 10-amdgpu.conf (I might not have recalled the name correctly) which all contain barely any information at all. As I use amdgpu drivers I have tried taking instructions I've found online to force loading of edid.bin which I generated using "Monitor Asset Manager" - A windows application , and saved as a .bin file - but have had no luck. the logs when I tried that seemed to indicate the conf file was written incorrectly. I have also tried achieving the same thing using kernel paramters which didn't work for me

drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=DP-1:edid/edid.bin

I understand I might have done things wrong when trying to work around this EDID issue, so I was hoping either there is a different way to solve this problem, or if someone can give simpler instructions to someone who is a linux noob to fix this problem. I've spent a lot of hours trying to solve this to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated!