# Enable 5120x2160 resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a new monitor and would like it to display at native resolution.

I followed the accepted answer here:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution
```

So, I ran `cvt 5120 2160 60` and copied the Modeline to `xrandr --newmode [modeline]`. However, when I run `xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 5120x2160_60.00` I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  50
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

Any suggestions on how I might get this to work, or other ways to make the desired resolution selectable? In case it matters, this is a second display connected to my laptop.

Comment: Update your question with the full results of `xrandr` and also the exact commands you ran and the exact output/results (not just a summary like xrandr --newmode [modeline]).

Comment: It's possible that HDMI does not support the resolution. I was able to set it directly in Display Settings of DP.