# Monitor settings changes after removing display cable

Tags: lubuntu, display-resolution, rdp

I have pc that is currently attached to monitor but i want to move it other place and access it just by using rdp. I have xrdp installed and set working. Resolution is right 1680x1050 when the display cable is connected. But when cable is removed i lose my monitor settings and resolution goes very low. Can i add somekind of virtual display that has same resolution without monitor attached to pc?

My Operating system is Lubuntu / LXQT

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the monitor, the system does not know what is your best resolution, because it does not get the information from the monitor any more. Therefore, it sets the resolution that will most probably work for any monitor.

You should add the resolution manually. Here is the answer how to do it [How do I set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution).

Comment: I think i have seen that site allready. I tried that again but the problem with that is after i unplug display cable OS won't find any monitors.

xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 0

When cable was attached it found VGA-1

Comment: @Joonas I assumed you were using HDMI. VGA connections AREN'T hot plugable. Sooner or later you'll break one or another or both.

Comment: When the cable was on i tried to add display settings using xrandr. Unplugged vga cable when pc was turned off. Then started pc and my resolution is now 1024x768 and no monitors to be found. I'm connecting to pc with rdp.

Comment: Try to run `xrandr` or `xrandr -q`, when the monitor is connected and see what resolution is selected and to which output it is connected. Than use the same settings for setting it up without monitor.