# How to fix resolution stuck at 640x480 with an nVidia card that relies on deprecated proprietary 304 driver?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xrandr, nomodeset

I had to include the directive 'nomodeset' during and after installation of Ubuntu 22.04 due to screen corruption/artifacts that couldn't display any useful information for navigation.

The main downside with this, is that the resolution is stuck at 640x480, whereas the monitor (Hanns G HW223D) support 1680 x 1050. Holding the 'Windows Flag' key on the keyboard allowed me to move window around to view and select necessary button such as next or back.

I followed the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution) to create a new resolution using xrandr and got the response
**Configure crtc 0 failed**.

The following were the outputs displayed as I typed each command, I also tried without '-r'

```
DS3:~$ cvt -r 1680 1050 60
# 1680x1050 59.88 Hz (CVT 1.76MA-R) hsync: 64.67 kHz; pclk: 119.00 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050R"  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync
```

Append last line to xrandr

```
DS3:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050R"  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Monitor name is given as default instead of DVI-D-0; graphics card is connected with a 'DVI-D single link' cable.

```
DS3:~$ xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

It seems it took a while for the maximum resolution to be recognized

```
DS3:~$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        0.00* 
  1680x1050R (0x535) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
    h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
    v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
DS3:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode default 1680x1050R
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
DS3:~$ sudo xrandr --output default --mode 1680x1050R
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 640x480 (desired size 1680x1050)
```

Maximum resolution is now recognized

```
DS3:~$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 1680 x 1050
```

Failure of xrandr to assingn new resolution

```
DS3:~$sudo xrandr --addmode default 1680x1050R
DS3:~$sudo xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080R
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Additionally, the following does not work:

```
DS3:~$ xrandr -s 1680x1050R
Failed to change the screen configuration!
DS3:~$ xrandr -s 1680x1050
Failed to change the screen configuration!
```

Output of --verbose, and as noted earlier I tried cvt without the '-r'

```
DS3:~$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 (0x524) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x523
    Timestamp:  7970560
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  640x480 (0x524)  0.000MHz *current
        h: width   640 start    0 end    0 total  640 skew    0 clock   0.00KHz
        v: height  480 start    0 end    0 total  480           clock   0.00Hz
  1680x1050R (0x535) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1680x1050_60.00 (0x54e) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050_30.00 (0x55b) 67.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1736 end 1896 total 2112 skew    0 clock  32.08KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1071           clock  29.95Hz
```

I've confirmed Ubuntu recognizes the video card, and that the Nouveau drivers are present.

```
DS3:~$ lspci -k | grep -iEA5 'vga|display|3d'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G70 [GeForce 7800 GT] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. G70 [GeForce 7800 GT]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

DS3:~$ lsmod | grep nouveau
nouveau              2306048  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    86016  2 drm_ttm_helper,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        311296  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
video                  61440  1 nouveau
wmi                    32768  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
drm                   622592  4 drm_kms_helper,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,nouveau
```

The monitor and the video card are from the year 2007, 15 years old. The following forum [post](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=707553#p707553), seems to suggest, the graphics card is more to blame. Ubuntu with kernel 4.15 or greater, will not permit installation of proprietary nVidia 304 drivers. I also tried 800x600 during the installation phase, and got the same crtc 0 failed.

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E6300 1.8 ghz
Motherboard : Gigabyte DS3 with 965P chipset
Ram: 2x1gb + 2x2gb = 6gb ram
Misc: Intel solid state driver 160 MB/s read speed

Comment: Your details make this confusing; you mention 22.04 but also 4.15 kernel (*an older kernel than 22.04 comes with or supports*) so are you using Ubuntu?.  As '*drivers*' are kernel modules; the '*driver*' needs to be built to support the kernel for it to work, thus kernel matters. As Nvidia kernel modules are closed-source (*proprietary*) you may need to ask them to compile/build a *kernel module* (aka '*driver*') to work on more modern kernels, or use the open-source alternatives Nvidia have suggested as replacements.  But please clarify your OS/release & kernel as details '*clash*'

Comment: I was implying, if I wanted to install the proprietary driver, I would have to downgrade to a version of Ubuntu that utilizes a kernel version less than 4.15, which is version 16.04; I'm wondering if I can change the resolution with the present release of 22.04.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2442347&p=13953113#post13953113

Comment: What is the rest of your hardware? CPU model, amount of RAM, etc..

Comment: It looks like Nvidia stopped maintaining the proprietary driver for that card back in 2017.  Have you tried to use the open source driver nouveau instead? Your CPU is also a bit below the recommended minimum specifications and mismatched RAM is not ideal, so don't rule out the possibility that some of your issues could be with your other hardware. You might consider installing a lighter desktop flavor like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. GNOME is a bit bulky with its use of system resources.