# Unable to change resolution to 3440 x 1440

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

I have an ultrawide monitor with intel hd 510 graphics. I just want my monitor to display its native resolution of 3440 x 1440.  It wasn't an option, so I used the `xrandr` protocol to create a `3440x1440_60.00` added to my display option.  However when I select that resolution it acts like it changed it, but the screen resolution won't change. If I select any of the other available resolutions, it will change to those. But it just doesn't change to the 3440x1440 resolution.  If I force it manually, the screen goes black for a few seconds then this error shows:

```
sharemore@Marx:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 3440x1440_60.00

xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Any idea why it won't change?

Comment: hdmi or DisplayPort? The graphics card can only handle 30fps at that resolution with HDMI, 60fps requires DisplayPort. Also, are you using xorg or wayland? xrandr won't work to configure monitors with Wayland, it only works with xorg (hence the 'x'). Also, how did you add the resolution? did you generate a modeline using `cvt`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: I used the cvt modeline.  When I did, it generated 59.97 fps, so that is why I did the _60.00.  I don't know how to generate a modeline for 30.00.  How do I determine wayland vs. xorg?  I'm on ubuntu 20.04.  Thanks for the help :D