# Setting custom resolution with xrandr running surface linux

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, surface

Running 22.04 on an old Surface laptop. I'm trying to set a custom resolution for a 34" external monitor connected w/ HDMI but it doesn't seem to want to "stay". I can connect 1920x1080 monitors fine and it works without a problem, but when I try to select my new resolution on the drop down, it just defaults to the previous one. I followed this post: [How do I set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution) and created a ~/.xprofile file which seemed to work.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm not a hardware expert so I'm not sure if I need to update drivers or if this is some incompatibility with the Surface kernel. Not a linux expert either by any means, so something might be super obviously wrong with my approach.

Thanks :)

[image]
[image]