# Configuring Ubuntu for 1920 x 1080 (16:9) Resolution on monitor connected via VGA to HDMI converter

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdmi, vga

I have a laptop running Ubuntu with both HDMI and VGA ports. I've connected two monitors to these ports—one directly using an HDMI cable and the other through a VGA to HDMI converter.

***Problem:***
The monitor connected via the VGA to HDMI converter is currently limited to a resolution of 1024 x 768 (4:3). Meanwhile, the monitor connected to the HDMI port displays at 1920 x 1080 (16:9). The laptop's built-in display also operates at 1920 x 1080 (16:9).

**How can I configure Ubuntu to enable the monitor connected via the VGA to HDMI converter to support a resolution of 1920 x 1080 (16:9)?**

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the output of `xrandr`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution)